# Mysql select records with offset

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a mysql `select` that will allow me to select (`LIMIT 8`) records after some changing number of first few matches;

```
select id
from customers
where name LIKE "John%"
Limit 8
```

So if i have a table with 1000 of johns with various last names
I want to be able to select records 500-508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the offset to the limit statement, like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM customers 
WHERE name LIKE "John%" 
LIMIT 8 OFFSET 500
```

Notice the `OFFSET 500` on the limit. That sets the 'start point' past the first 500 entries (at entry #501).

Therefor, entries #501, #502, #503, #504, #505, #506, #507 and #508 will be selected.

This can also be written:

```
LIMIT 500, 8
```

Personally, I don't like that as much and don't understand the order.

Pedantic point: 500-508 is 9 entries, so I had to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution please try executing the following  sql query

```
 select id  from customers where name LIKE "John%" Limit 500,8
```