# How do you load more post in news feed without loading previous loaded post?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

This code is in my index page:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY posting_id DESC LIMIT 15
```

```javascript
newPost = newPost + 15;
canBeLoaded = false;
$(".newsfeed").load("https://www.veenir.com/home/post/autoloadposts/posts.php", {
        newPost: newPost
    },
    function(b, c, d) {
        if (c == "success") {
            canBeLoaded = true;
            $(".loadingMorePostIndicator").html("<span></span>");
        }
    }
});
```

This code is in my autoloadposts folder; it gets the value of the loaded posts and adds 15, before reloading the posts from the database with the new limit each time the user reaches the bottom of the page:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY posting_id DESC LIMIT $newpostcount
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql select records with offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667358/mysql-select-records-with-offset)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one SELECT query by setting a different LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY posting_id DESC LIMIT $oldpostcount, 15 //$oldpostcount + 15 elements will be selected
```

The var `$oldpostcount` has to be your current called amount.
Lets say you have already called your first 15 items from your Database.
Then you set `$oldpostcount = 15;` and reload the page with this var.
Now all your posts from 15 to 30 will be selected. You can search for "MySQL Infinite Scroll" if you need more information about that.

Comment: It’s working fine, when the page first load, it loads 15 posts and when user scroll to the button it loads 30 the problem is the page is loading the previous loaded 15 posts and add 15. I believe this is consuming users mobile data. I want the previous one that is loaded shouldn’t load again it show be on the news feed while another 15 posts is added. Am using Jquery load() which I think is bad I should be using prepend(); But how will I know a particular post is loaded or not?